# how to delete resources with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, infrastructure-as-code

set up - a lambda project ( see file structure below) in terraform . in my gitlab-ci, in a build step , lambda code is zipped up at the root of the directory. everything works fine except, when i try to delete all resources in stg_destroy stage at the end , it complains that zip file is not there. how to run the destroy stage ?

```
foo
- tf
  - main.tf
  - backend.tf
  - output.tf
  - lambda
    - main.tf
    ...
- code
  - lambda
    - app.js
```

foo/tf/lambda/main.tf

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  filename                       = "lambda.zip"
  handler                        = "main.handler" 
  runtime                        = "python3.6" 
  source_code_hash               = source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(lambda.zip)
}
```

backend.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

gitlab-ci

```
buildStage:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd code/lambda zip ../../lambda.zip app.js
  

validateStage:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - echo "validation ..."

planStage:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - echo "Generating terraform plan and output to file 'plan' "
    - terraform plan --out plan
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - plan

applyStage:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply --auto-approve plan
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - terraform.tfstate

destroyStage:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - terraform destroy --auto-approve
  when: manual
  ...
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if your `buildStage` was executed in the same build as the `destroyStage`. Due to the `when` condition of the `destroyStage` I would assume it wasn't.
Looks like `aws_lambda_function` requires the zip file to exist also if you just want to destroy the resource. I'd say, you need to run the build stage before the `destroyStage` to ensure the zip file exists. (Just assumptions, not tested.)

Comment: What I'm also missing form the code you shared is a remote backend for Terraform. You need to persist the Terraform state between the different executions. If you do not specify any backend, Terraform will use a local backend. On a build agent, It is usually the case that workspace folders are wiped after each build and so the state gets lost. So the next issue I would expect you to run into is, that in the next build (apply) of your pipeline, Terraform will complain that a resource with the same name already exists.

Comment: @stdtom - thanks. yes i do have the backend, i updated the question. and buildstage was exectued in the same build as destroyStage. so i am assuming the zip file should exist, when it gets to that stage but it doesn't , do i need to specify somehow to persist the artifact from one stage to another.

Comment: Yes, I assume, that would be required. The `artifacts` statement would be your friend here. :-)
But even then I would expect that `terraform init` is required in each of the stages plan, apply, and destroy.

Comment: @stdom - could send me an example , if you know how to use artifacts correctly.